# How to save all depth frames in OpenNI kinect

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, openni, color-depth

I've wrote a program to save all the depth frames of the Kinect depth images in OpenNI. I've used the simple viewer sample. The problem that not all the frames are saved!! I run my program for 10 sec and around 20 images only are saved although the application is set with 30fps!!
Could anyone please advise?

Comment: why don you use the NiViewer application and save an .oni file ? You can then write a really basic application that loads the .oni file, creates the depth generator and saves the current frame, moves to the next and repeats until the last frame

Comment: I've tried that, I've saved the movies as .Oni file then play it and work on it but still the same results! May be not all the 30 fps are full of data thats why it only captures the ones with data?

Comment: can you post some code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

My colleague uses a 2-phase extraction. First write the images in binary, in order to avoid losing time during encoding or conversions. (You can use `System.IO.FileStream` and `BinaryWriter` for that). And then in another program, read the binary files to get raw depth or color images. You might make use of Matlab, OpenCV or another utility for this second part.

But keep in mind that, even this approach might cause some skipped/dropped frames. Personally, I've never achieved to obtain a constant 30 fps for a long period.